# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - Encrypt worklight.properties

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security, worklight-server

I am trying to follow the steps in [Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Fr_storing_properties_in_encrypted_format.html) to encypt sensitive information in worklight.properties.

In this step,

*All of the encrypted values use the same secret key, which is stored in the special     variable called worklight_enc_password. This variable is defined as an operating system environment variable:

On Windows systems: Set an environment variable under the user running the IBM Worklight Server. When running under a Windows NT service, define the password as a service property by using the registry editor. For more information, see the Microsoft support website.*

I have tried to add worklight_enc_password in register editor under HKKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment and deploy the application. However, in SystemOut.log, it kept returning **"java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot decrypt value for the property xxx.enc. The encryption password should be defined in the environment variable xxx.enc"**

May I know where should I set this variable "worklight_enc_password" in Windows XP?

Environment: Windows XP, Worklight 5.0.6, WAS ND 8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WAS, the worklight_enc_password can be added in Servers > WebSphere application servers > server name (e.g. server1) > Java and Process Management > Process definition > Environment Entries.

The reason is that the variable is actually retrieved by System.getEnv("worklight_enc_password") in worklight library.

Hope this help to other people.